# Centering image in Excel

Tags: html, css, excel, asp-classic, center

I've been trying to center an image in an Excel export file using Classic ASP. I tried everything and resorted to CSS. CSS didn't work (examples below):

```
     img {
position: absolute;
top: 0; bottom:0; left: 0; right:0;
margin: auto;
 }
```

and

```
   img.center {
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
  }
```

I tried putting the image in a `div` and centering the `div`. That also didn't work. I have the image in an `img` tag like this:

```
  <img border=0 id= "img" name= "img" src="pic.jpg"  height ="100" width= "1000">
```

When I export the file to Excel and open it, the picture is always to the very left.

Comment: What is the code you use to place the image in the file?

Comment: How can HTML and CSS be used to place an image in an Excel file? Are you coding ASP Classic with VBScript or JavaScript?

Comment: @ExcelHero  <img border=0 id= "img" name= "img"src="pic.jpg"  height ="100" width= "1000">

that line adds the image. I tried using <center>(outdated, i know) and putting that line inside a centered div but that also didnt work.

Comment: Please read my new comment that came through about five seconds before yours.

Comment: @ExcelHero Javascript.

Comment: So, we need to see the JavaScript.

Comment: @ExcelHero sorry, for this file...I only use HTML CSS and Classic ASP to generate the excel file. the following lines generate the file:

 Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
  Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "filename=""General Report.xls"""

Comment: Ahh. Now I understand what you are doing...

Comment: To center an object in a container, the container needs to have a defined width. Excel sheets don't have a defined width.

Comment: @Martha so what can be done?

Comment: @DanielB: stop thinking of it as centering, I guess, since "center" has no meaning in this context, yet obviously you have something in mind when you use the term. Maybe align the image to the edge of a particular cell, where you select the cell according to whatever it is you're imagining when you think "centered"?

Comment: @Martha the Image is at the top of the table, so there are no cells to align too. The problem isn't just centering. The problem is moving the image anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While simple Excel files can be created through ASP Classic simply by setting the headers for the page, you will often need more control.

Please take a look at this: http://www.crydust.be/blog/2009/03/02/generate-excel-files-in-asp-classic/

Code repostedform Kristof Neirynck's blog here:

```
<%@LANGUAGE="JAVASCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>
<%

function getData(connectionString, sql){
    var result = null;
    var adStateOpen = 1;
    var connection = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.CONNECTION");
    try{
        connection.Open(connectionString);
    } catch(e1){
        return null;
    }
    if (connection.State !== adStateOpen) {
        return null;
    }
    try{
        var recordset = connection.Execute(sql);
    } catch(e2){
        return null;
    }
    if (!recordset.EOF) {
        result = recordset.GetRows().toArray();
        recordset.Close();
    }
    recordset = null;
    connection.Close();
    connection = null;
    return result;
}


function writeCsvHttpHeaders(filename){
    Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
    Response.Charset = "utf-8";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition",
            "attachment; filename="+filename+".csv");
}

function writeXlsHttpHeaders(filename){
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    Response.Charset = "utf-8";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition",
            "attachment; filename="+filename+".xls");
}

function getXlsStart(){
    return ""
    + "<html>\n"
    + "<head>\n"
    + "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" "
    + "content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\">\n"
    + "<style type=\"text/css\">\n"
    + "html, body, table {\n"
    + "    margin: 0;\n"
    + "    padding: 0;\n"
    + "    font-size: 11pt;\n"
    + "}\n"
    + "table, th, td { \n"
    + "    border: 0.1pt solid #D0D7E5;\n"
    + "    border-collapse: collapse;\n"
    + "    border-spacing: 0;\n"
    + "}\n"
    + "</style>\n"
    + "</head>\n"
    + "<body>\n"
    + "<table>\n"
    + "";
}

function getXlsEnd(){
    return ""
    + "</table>\n"
    + "</body>\n"
    + "</html>"
    + "";
}

function csvEscape(val){
    if (typeof val === "number") {
        return val.toString(10).replace(".", ",");
    } else if (typeof val === "string") {
        if (val.indexOf("\"") !== -1) {
            return "\""+val.replace(/"/g, "\"\"")+"\"";
        } else if (val.indexOf(";") !== -1) {
            return "\""+val+"\"";
        } else {
            return val;
        }
    } else if (val === null) {
        return "#NULL#";
    } else if (val === undefined) {
        return "#UNDEFINED#";
    } else {
        return "#ERROR#";
    }
}

function writeCsv(filename, data, columnCount){
    writeCsvHttpHeaders(filename);
    // utf-8 BOM (very important for special characters)
    Response.Write("\uFEFF");
    for (var i=0, il=data.length; i<il; i+=columnCount) {
        for (var j=0; j<columnCount; j++) {
            Response.Write(csvEscape(data[i+j]));
            if (j !== columnCount-1) {
                Response.Write(";");
            }
        }
        Response.Write("\n");
        // prevent Response Buffering Limit Exceeded
        if (i % 1000 === 0) {
            Response.Flush();
        }
    }
}

function xlsEscape(val){
    if (typeof val === "number") {
        return val.toString(10).replace(".", ",");
    } else if (typeof val === "string") {
        return Server.HTMLEncode(val);
    } else if (val === null)  {
        return "#NULL#";
    } else if (val === undefined)  {
        return "#UNDEFINED#";
    } else {
        return "#ERROR#";
    }
}

function writeXls(filename, data, columnCount){
    writeXlsHttpHeaders(filename);
    Response.Write(getXlsStart());
    for (var i=0, il=data.length; i<il; i+=columnCount) {
        Response.Write("<tr>");
        for (var j=0; j<columnCount; j++) {
            Response.Write("<td>");
            Response.Write(xlsEscape(data[i+j]));
            Response.Write("</td>");
        }
        Response.Write("</tr>\n");
        // prevent Response Buffering Limit Exceeded
        if (i % 1000 === 0) {
            Response.Flush();
        }
    }
    Response.Write(getXlsEnd());
}

function main(){
    var filetype = Request.QueryString("filetype")();
    Var connectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;"
    + "Data Source=LAPTOP\\SQLEXPRESS;"
    + "User ID=internal;"
    + "Password=internal;"
    + "Initial Catalog=trees_in_sql";
    Var sql = ""
    + "SELECT id \n"
    + ", name \n"
    + "FROM People \n"
    + ";";
    var filename = "filename";
    var columnCount = 2;

    var data = getData(connectionString, sql);
    if (data !== null) {
        Response.Clear();
        if (filetype === "csv") {
            writeCsv(filename, data, columnCount);
        } else {
            writeXls(filename, data, columnCount);
        }
    } else {
        Response.Write("Error, no data found");
    }
    Response.End();
}

main();

%>
```

.

**IMPORTANT**

Regarding images specifically, you should look at this: http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Scripting/ASP/Q_27115638.html

From the above link:

```
<!--#include file="functions.asp"-->
<%
response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
thedate = CStr(Now())
groupid = request.querystring("groupid")

GroupName = getGroupName(groupid)

datetimestring = Replace(FormatDateTime(Now(), vbShortDate), "/", "-") & "_" & Replace(FormatDateTime(Now(), vbShortTime), ":", "")
response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=GroupAttendanceExport_" & GroupName & "_" & datetimestring & ".xls"

response.write "<html><body><table>"
response.write "<tr><td><img border=0 src='https://www.example.org/xxx_Logo_small.jpg'></td></tr>"
response.write "<tr><td></td></tr>"
response.write "<tr><td></td></tr>"
response.write "<tr><td></td></tr>"
response.write "<tr><td></td></tr>"
response.write "<tr><td></td></tr>"

response.write "<tr><td > Attendance</td></tr>"
response.write "</table>"

MORE CODE HERE
………
………
………
………

response.write "</body></html>"
```

.

**UPDATE**

It sounds like you need to use OpenXML instead of HTML.

Here is an example of how to insert an image into a specific cell using OpenXML: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/157e2fab-ed30-43a5-9824-e144d673a5b7/insert-images-into-specific-excel-cells-using-openxml?forum=oxmlsdk

Comment: thank you for the quick response. I have used the attached code before in other projects but the same problem persists. The link regarding the picture doesn't allow me to see the verified answer.

Comment: Running the 2ndlink produces what I have so far, An image in the top left of the screen. I need to somehow manipulate the location of the image and bring it to the center.

Comment: Then you will likely need to write out Open XML instead of HTML.

Comment: @DanielB Please see the UPDATE at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: so I would assume there is no option in regular HTML?

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. I really appreciate them.

Comment: My pleasure. Hopefully you can accept the answer even if the answer is not what you wanted to hear.  :)